# install dsfont package on windows

Tags: math-mode, packages

I need the dsfont package but I get an error

> dsfont.sty not found

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
   ...
\end{document}
```

how can I download it and install it with another way?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/doublestroke?lang=en shows it is part of miktex and texlive as `doublestroke`  you have not said which tex you are using, but in texlive `tlmgr update doublestroke` should be all you need

Comment: I use miktex with tex maker

Comment: miktex has a similar package manager but I'll leave a miktex user to answer with details as I haven't used it. But you should not need to download or install anything by hand

Comment: that's work when I downloaded "doublestroke package", thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With MiKTeX, launch `MiKTeX Package Manager` (Admin mode), type doublestroke in the `Name` form window, click on `Filter`, then right-click on `doublestroke` and choose `Install`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/doublestroke

shows it is part of miktex and texlive as `doublestroke`

I texlive

```
 tlmgr update doublestroke
```

would work, or the equivalent in the miktex package manager.